# Rvmrc file not selecting the gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, gemset, rvmrc

I am using `rvm` 1.26.2 & `Ubuntu` 14.0.4
I have to create separate gem sets and `.rvmrc` file for each project, but the `.rvmrc` file isn't selecting the gemset.

can any one tell why  the application ignore `.rvmrc` file ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please use `.rvmrc` script just in case you have use complex actions for triggering the folder change. In simple case just use system file pair: `.ruby-version`, `.ruby-gemset`.

```
$ cat .ruby-version
2.1.4

$ cat .ruby-gemset
your-project-name
```